# Django Form - checking every object without showing them

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I created two models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name of country", max_length=100, default="Australia")
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="number of country", default="1")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class World(models.Model):
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="New Map", max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to give user possibility to create new world on site, but during creating he can't uncheck any object from a list (every object must be checked but he can't see them). 
I created a form.py:

```
class WorldForm(forms.ModelForm):

    country = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Country.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = World
        fields = ('name',)
```

But this code gives user possibility to choose objects and uncheck some. How to change it?

The best idea for me is when user creates his "world" - he can only type a name of world and he didn't see names of countries but every object "Country" will be includes in his "world" . Is that possible? How can i change code in forms to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we could achieve that by overriding the [`ModelForm.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method:

```
class WorldForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = World
                fields = ('name',)

        def save(self, commit=True):
            super(WorldForm, self).save(commit=False)
            is_new = not self.instance.pk
            self.instance.save()

            if is_new:
                # It's a new world. Fill it with countries!
                self.instance.country.add(*Country.objects.all())
            else:
                self._save_m2m()

            return self.instance
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Form now looks like i wanted it, but when i save it i get an error(do you have an idea?): TypeError at /world/

save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Comment: Sorry, it's just a typo, take a look at the updated `save()` signature. I've added a kwarg there.

Comment: Ok, I added 'commit=True' to save() signature and now i get: "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet", i tried change it but i don't know where exactly is the mistake, but probably this world is created without any country again. Is it something with "is_new" ?

Comment: No, it's my another mistake, please add the `*` to the Countries.